# why does spark appends 'WHERE 1=0' at the end of sql query

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to execute a simple mysql query using Apache Spark and create a data frame. But for some reasons spark appends `'WHERE 1=0'` at the end of the query which I want to execute and throws an exception stating `'You have an error in your SQL syntax'`.

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").appName("rddjoin"). getOrCreate()
 val mhost = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/registry"
val mprop = new java.util.Properties
mprop.setProperty("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")mprop.setProperty("user", "root")
mprop.setProperty("password", "root")
val q= """select id from loaded_item"""
val res=spark.read.jdbc(mhost,q,mprop)
res.show(10)
```

And the exception is as below:

```
18/02/16 17:53:49 INFO StateStoreCoordinatorRef: Registered StateStoreCoordinator endpoint
Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select id from loaded_item WHERE 1=0' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:944)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2484)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1966)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation.<init>(JDBCRelation.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:307)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:178)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.jdbc(DataFrameReader.scala:193)
    at GenerateReport$.main(GenerateReport.scala:46)
    at GenerateReport.main(GenerateReport.scala)
18/02/16 17:53:50 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
```

Answer (score 10):

The second parameter of your call to `spark.read.jdbc` is not correct. Instead of specifing a sql query, you should either use a table name qualified with schema or a valid SQL query with an alias. In your case this would be `val q="registry.loaded_item"`. Another option if you want to provide addional parameters (maybe for a where statement) is to use the other versions of [DataframeReader.jdbc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html#jdbc(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.util.Properties)).

Btw: the reason why you see the strange looking query `WHERE 1=0` is that Spark tries to infer the schema of your data frame without loading any actual data. This query is guaranteed never to deliver any results, but the query result's metadata can be used by Spark to get the schema information.

Comment: Thanks Werner! That explains a lot. Actually I am trying to execute a big query and which has this table. select distinct i.id from asset a JOIN item i ON a.latest_item_id = i.id JOIN loaded_item li ON li.id = i.id INNER JOIN jrn_article ja ON i.id = ja.id  INNER JOIN publication p ON a.publication_id = p.id   where li.dead = false and a.dead = false and (p.id is null or p.dead = false) and a.item_type = :itemType  and a.origin_id = :originId  and li.item_status IN ('DELIVER_PASS')
 Thats the query. Not really sure how should I go with creating dataframe for this. any help appreciated.

Comment: You have three options:  
1. create a view in your databse and then load the view as described in the answer.  
2. create Spark dataframes for all tables that are part of your query (asset, item, loaded_item, ...) and then use dataframe logic to get the wanted results  
3. hide your query behind a subquery as described [here](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/sql-databases.html#pushdown-query-to-database-engine)

Comment: A bit of correction: that 2nd parameter (`dbtable`) can be either *table name qualified with schema* or a *valid `SQL` query* as told [here](https://medium.com/@radek.strnad/tips-for-using-jdbc-in-apache-spark-sql-396ea7b2e3d3). However in case it's a query, it has to be enclosed in parenthesis and aliased like this `"(select id from registry.loaded_item) AS sql"`

Comment: @y2k-shubham Thanks for the hint. I have updated my answer.