# Read mariaDB4J table into spark DataSet using JDBC

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, apache-spark-sql, mariadb

I am trying to read table from MariaDB4J via jdbc using the following command:

```
Dataset<Row> jdbcDF = spark.read()
                    .format("jdbc")
                    .option("url", url)
                    .option("dbtable", String.format("SELECT userID FROM %s;", TableNAME))
                    .load();
```

I get the following error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT userID FROM MYTABLE; WHERE 1=0' at line 1
```

I am not sure where the WHERE comes from and why I get this error...
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter supplied to the dbtable option is not correct. Instead of specifing a sql query, you should either use a table name qualified with the schema or a valid SQL query with an alias.

```java
Dataset<Row> jdbcDF = spark.read()
                      .format("jdbc")
                      .option("url", url)
                      .option("dbtable", String.format("(SELECT userID FROM %s) as table_alias", tableNAME))                
                      .load();
```

Your question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48827041/2129801), so forgive me if I [quote myself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48830581/2129801):

> The reason why you see the strange looking query WHERE 1=0 is that Spark tries to infer the schema of your data frame without loading any actual data. This query is guaranteed never to deliver any results, but the query result's metadata can be used by Spark to get the schema information.